# Spring Authorization Server `JdbcOAuth2AuthorizationService` does not save custom User object

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-security, spring-authorization-server

I'm using Spring Authorization Server with a custom `UserDetailsService`. I have extended `User` class to add two extra properties (`AuthenticatedUser extends User`) and once the user is authenticated, my `UserDetailsService` returns this `AuthenticatedUser` object.

I tried to implement `JdbcOAuth2AuthorizationService` to store my authorizations (with a Postgres db) and I noticed that when the `JdbcOAuth2AuthorizationService` inserts the authorization to the table, it stores the principal as `User` object not as an `AuthenticatedUser` object.

In the db, this is what I see under the `attributes` column.

```
"principal":{"@class":"org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User","password":null,"username":"demouser","authorities":["java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableSet",[{"@class":"org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority","authority":"engineering"},{"@class":"org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority","authority":"manager"}]],"accountNonExpired":true,"accountNonLocked":true,"credentialsNonExpired":true,"enabled":true},"credentials":null}}
```

In the correct scenario, `org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User` should be `com.my.package.models.AuthenticatedUser` and it should contain the extra properties I have extended.

By doing some debugging I managed to figure out that the correct class is being passed until the following method in `JdbcTemplate`.

```
public int update(String sql, @Nullable PreparedStatementSetter pss) throws DataAccessException {
        return update(new SimplePreparedStatementCreator(sql), pss);
}
```

In here, `pss` has the correct class but still it saves the previous `User` class in the db.
My question is, does anyone know why is this happening and how can I solve this issue and store `AuthenticatedUser` class in the db.

TIA